# Read multiple .mat files and store them in a cell

Tags: arrays, matlab, computer-vision, mat

Previous `.mat` file reading questions have been looked at, this is a little more specific so please bear with me.

I have a large dataset of files named:

```
int_f0270.mat
int_f0271.mat
...
```

These are image matrices that I need to read into MATLAB so that I can perform sequential operations on them. The code I am using is below:

```
   for i = 270:273
   filename = strcat('int_f0',int2str(i),'.mat');
   load(filename);
   end
```

This works for the first file (e.g. `int_f0271.mat`), but fails to load any more .mat files into picture.

The only output I get is this:

[image]

which is the correct size and can be displayed as an image but I need this for all my data set. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ImageCell = {};
for i = 270:273
filename = strcat('int_f0',int2str(i),'.mat');
load(filename);
ImageCell{i-269} = C;
clear C
end
```

Comment: This is great thanks. Can you expand on how to read the image in the ImageCell please? I am new to working with images in MATLAB.

Comment: You'r welcome, Now each `ImageCell{j}` is a picture. you can reach it like `imshow(ImageCell{1})`.